# Is it possible to perform a long press action to access app menu in BrowserStack?

Tags: java, android, appium, browserstack

I'm using BrowserStack to run tests for android devices. I need to perform a long press on an app to access its menu (like on the picture attached). How can it be performed in Java?

[image: menu]

Answer (score 0):

I would like to let you know that, should your query be able to successfully reproduce on a real device locally then you would be able to do it on Browserstack as well.

As per Appium documentation, you can Long Tap on the touch screen using finger motion events. You can refer to the following for more information:
http://appium.io/docs/en/commands/interactions/touch/long-press/

If you are able to long-press the app on a real device through your Appium code then that would be possible on Browserstack as well.

Comment: I know about long press action possibility inside app, but when I run a test, my app opens automatically. So I'm interested in possibility to perform long press before app opens